# Website url %20 to -

Tags: php

Good day! I have a problem that url adress shows space as %20 but i want it change to "-" symbol.

```
if( array_key_exists( "location" , $_GET ) )

{
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET [ "location" ],$connection );

    $source = mysql_query("SELECT `location` FROM `blog` WHERE `location` = '$id' LIMIT 5",$connection);

    if( mysql_num_rows( $source ) )
    {
        // print only name
        echo mysql_result( $source );
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $source );
```

Where should I add str_replace ? when i tryed to do this it just crashed.
   Thanks (:

Comment: The term you are looking for is [slug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug). Try googling for "url slug php" or such.

Comment: Please mark the best answer as accepted in order to help future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

PHP has a function for this. Use `urldecode()` following by a `str_replace()`

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: that will change it to a space (" "), not a -

Comment: @hanshenrik there's no builtin for turning %20 into "-", why would there be? `urldecode()` followed by `str_replace()` or equivalent is the way to go. +1

Comment: he didnt want to decode it, he wanted to corrupt his URL by replacing %20 (meaning space) to - (meaning - ) - which will corrupt his url data, while still valid urlencoding, the data will change..

Answer (score 1):

```
    $row = str_replace("%20","-",mysql_fetch_assoc( $source ));
```

PS: Stop using mysql_   , change to mysqli or PDO, because "mysql_ is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7." -- http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php 
mysql_ is insecure and slow and has been mostly unmaintained for years.

Comment: I wrote it in the correct place and there were nothing changed.

Comment: url still stayed with %20 spaces

Comment: Can you help out with it ?